# Длина массива undefined. NodeJS/Oracle

Tags: javascript, node.js, oracle

Пытаюсь привести выгрузку из **Oracle** в **Node.JS** к нормальному `JSON` вида:
`{
  "name": "Bob",
  "age": 21
}`

Мой код:

```
router.get('/policy',function(req, res) {

    oracledb.getConnection(
        cfg.database,
        function (err, connection) {
            if (err) {
                console.error(err.message);
                return;
            }
            connection.execute(`select * from * where *`, function(err, result) {

                var p = {};
                var results = result.rows;
                    if (err) {
                        res.status(501);
                        console.log(err.message);
                        doRelease(connection);
                        return;
                    } else {

                        for (var i = 0; i<= results.length; i) {
                            for (var j = 0; j <= results[i].length; j++) {

                                p.policyId = results[i][j];
                                p.policyNo = results[i][j];
                                p.status = results[i][j];

                            }

                        }


                        res.status(200);
                            // res.json(result);
                        doRelease(connection);
                        console.log(p);
                    }
                }
            )
```

И при обращении к `/policy` получаю ошибку:

> TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined

Если попытаться получить длину массива, в котором массивы:
- `console.log(results.length);` получаю значение (в данном случае 5);
- так же если получить длину оставшегося массива `console.log(results[0].length);` получаю значение (в данном случае 3), но через цикл `FOR` возвращается ошибка...

UPD.

Сделал кусок кода так:

```
for (var i = 0; i < results.length; i++) {

   p.policyId = results[i][0];
   p.policyNo = results[i][1];
   p.status = results[i][2];

}
res.send(p);
```

но получаю только 1 результат.
Если `res.send(p);` переношу в цикл, то получаю ошибку:

> Error: Can't set headers after they are sent.

Но ошибка понятна, только не понятно, как отправить все результаты цикла...

Comment: Если у вас отсчет элементов идет с нуля, вы уверены, что `i<= length` правильное условие... Может все таки строго `i < length` (без равно) ?

Comment: При таком условии: `i < length`, запрос "повисает"

Comment: Хм. как это он повисает ? Но если элементов 5 и первый из них с индексом 0, то `results[5]` в любом случае не существует, максимальный индекс в массиве должен быть 4

Comment: @Mike Отредактировал вопрос, посмотрите, пжл

Comment: Вбитие сообщения об ошибке в гугл сказало, что функция send отправляет страницу целиком и ее нельзя использовать несколько раз. рекомендуют использовать write(). https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7042340/error-cant-set-headers-after-they-are-sent-to-the-client

Comment: у вас `i` вместо `i++` в первом цикле.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Решил задачу так:

```
const result = rows.map((row) => {
  const {D, E, R} = row
  return r =  {
  A: D,
  B: E,
  C: R
}
```